# python 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, sqlite

The error I receive:

> File "database.py", line 6, in 
>       class data:   File "database.py", line 17, in data
>       self.dbcommit() NameError: name 'self' is not defined

My code:

```
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
class data:
   def __init__(self,dbname):
       self.con=sqlite.connect(dbname)
   def __del__(self):
       self.con.close()
   def dbcommit(self):
       self.con.commit()
   def createtable(self):
       self.con.execute('create table db(ind,w)')
       self.dbcommit()
e=data('search.db')
e.createtable()
```

Comment: Could you check that the indentation of what you have posted here is identical to what you're running? The stack trace you posted suggests that it might be different, and it could well be the source of your trouble, but it's hard to be sure without some clarification.

Comment: sorry , I posted the code mistakely. but it still
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database.py", line 3, in <module>
    class data:
  File "database.py", line 12, in data
    self.dbcommit()
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

It's an indentation issue.
The `def`s after `__init__` need to be indented the same amount for Python to consider them to be part of the class.

Try:

```
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite

class data:
    def __init__(self,dbname):
        self.con=sqlite.connect(dbname)
    def __del__(self):
        self.con.close()
    def dbcommit(self):
        self.con.commit()
    def createtable(self):
        self.con.execute('create table db(ind,w)')
        self.dbcommit()

e=data('search.db')
e.createtable()
```

Comment: There would be a different error using the OP's code as posted, `eAttributeError: 'data' object has no attribute 'createtable'`

Comment: sorry , I posted the code mistakely. but it still Traceback (most recent call last): File "database.py", line 3, in <module> class data: File "database.py", line 12, in data self.dbcommit() NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is almost certainly caused by mixed tabs and spaces. Take a look at the backtrace you posted:

```
File "database.py", line 6, in <module>
    class data:
File "database.py", line 17, in data
    self.dbcommit()
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

This means that the exception occurred on line 17, as you already know, but the very suspicious thing here is how it got to line 17. You would expect it to get to line 17 because it's executing createtable, so you would have thought that the previous line in the backtrace would show the call `e.createtable()`.

To understand exactly what's happening requires understanding how Python creates classes themselves. When Python comes to a class declaration, it executes the indented code inside the class block. Normally, that will be a bunch of method declarations (which are really just function declarations) and maybe some assignments, and "executing" a method declaration simply adds that method to the current namespace. At the end of the class block, Python bundles up everything in the namespace and uses them to make the class itself. But there's nothing stopping you from putting any old code inside the class block, and it will run once when the class definition is executed. And that appears to be what we're seeing here.

I can reproduce your exception with this code:

```
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
class data:
    def __init__(self,dbname):
        self.con=sqlite.connect(dbname)
    def __del__(self):
        self.con.close()
    def dbcommit(self):
        self.con.commit()
    def createtable(self):
        self.con.execute('create table db(ind,w)')
    self.dbcommit()
e=data('search.db')
e.createtable()
```

Note the different indentation of `self.dbcommit()`.

So, why is this happening even though you seem to have the correct indentation in your file? I think you probably have mixed tabs and spaces and are using an editor that shows tabs as 4-space indents, which is pretty common now. However, when Python encounters tabs, it treats them as *8-space* indents. You might have this:

```
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
class data:
TAB>def __init__(self,dbname):
TAB>TAB>self.con=sqlite.connect(dbname)
TAB>def __del__(self):
TAB>TAB>self.con.close()
TAB>def dbcommit(self):
TAB>TAB>self.con.commit()
TAB>def createtable(self):
TAB>TAB>self.con.execute('create table db(ind,w)')
________self.dbcommit()
e=data('search.db')
e.createtable()
```

But Python is seeing it like this:

```
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
class data:
TAB---->def __init__(self,dbname):
TAB---->TAB---->self.con=sqlite.connect(dbname)
TAB---->def __del__(self):
TAB---->TAB---->self.con.close()
TAB---->def dbcommit(self):
TAB---->TAB---->self.con.commit()
TAB---->def createtable(self):
TAB---->TAB---->self.con.execute('create table db(ind,w)')
________self.dbcommit()
e=data('search.db')
e.createtable()
```

You can check if this is the case by running `python -tt SCRIPTNAME.py`, because this will cause Python to generate an error if it encounters mixed tabs and spaces. If so, the solution is to replace all the tabs with spaces and just stick to spaces from now on. This is the recommended way to write Python scripts: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces

Comment: Thanks, but I do not have enough reputation for you %>_<% it is so kind of you

Answer (score 0):

That should work. My guess would be that you misspelled `self` in the declaration of dbcommit, something like this

```
def dbcommit(slef):
    ...
```